# Make all values in a dictionary lower-case

Tags: python, dictionary, lowercase

Python

How do you take a dictionary (consisting only of strings) and make all of the values in said dictionary lowercase?

Comment: `{k: v.lower() for k, v in d.items()}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_dict ={"first":"ABC","second":"abC","third":"aBc"}
for i in my_dict.keys():
    my_dict[i] = my_dict[i].lower()
```

Update (for `list` as dictionary value):

```
my_dict ={"first":"ABC","second":"abC","third":"aBc","fourth":["Avd","Dfe"]}
for i in my_dict.keys():
    if type(my_dict[i]) is list:
        my_dict[i]=  [j.lower() for j in my_dict[i]]
    else:
        my_dict[i] = my_dict[i].lower()
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'first': 'abc', 'second': 'abc', 'third': 'abc', 'fourth': ['avd', 'dfe']}
```

Comment: I should have clarified. But some of my dict keys have a list as a variable. So in the case of your example it may look like: `"first": ["ABC","DEF"]`

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is perfect!